# how is $p\to{\sim} p$ not a contradiction??

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

i understand that a contradiction is a proposition that Is always false, and in this case if p is false the implication is true, but in English this sentence sounds so contradictory: "if it's blue, then it's not blue" how does this even make sense?

Comment: $p\land (p\to\lnot p)$ is a contradiction, if you only have the implication, maybe $p$ is false.

Comment: Check with a truth table: for $v(p)= \text F$ we have: $v(p \to \lnot p)=\text T$.

Comment: The issue is that when we assert "if p, then q", we are **not** asserting p (and neither q).

Comment: What we are asserting is: "if it is the case that p, then it is the case that not-p". Is this absurd ? No; if p is True, this statement is simply False.

Comment: $A\implies B$ deos not say anything about the case that $A$ is false. $B$ can therefore be true or false in this case , the implication is still valid.

Comment: Additionally, also a false statement "makes sense". "$2=3$" is a false, but not a non-sensical statement.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA,  You said:  if p is True, this statement is simply False.  What I am struggling with is that it is not correct:  if p is False, this statement is False.

Answer (score 4):

A naive person learns to recite the alphabet and thinks that means he's a great genius.

Another naive person learns to recite the alphabet and realizes that's a bare beginning of erudition and he must do a great deal more. He continues his schooling and goes on to become the author of the general theory of relativity.

Of the first naive person, one says: "If he's genius only because of that, then he's *not* a genius."

Thus "If $p$ then not $p.$"

This would be a contradiction only if $p$ were actually true.

Comment: +1, very nice explanation!

Answer (score 4):

> "if it's blue, then it's not blue" how does this even make sense?

Let me rephrase:

"IF it's blue, then it's not blue"

OK, so it cannot be blue, for IF it were blue, THEN it's be both blue and not blue, and we'd have a problem.

OK, so it is not blue ... and note: if it is not blue ... then there is no problem at all!

So: if you ever have $p \to \neg p$, then we can conclude $\neg p$ ... and there is no contradiction.

Indeed: $p \to \neg p \Leftrightarrow \neg p$

But yes, many beginning students of logic get that one wrong. They believe $p \to \neg p \Leftrightarrow \bot$. No, we have $p \land \neg p \Leftrightarrow \bot$, but that's different. So, you're far from the only one! It's a classic, really.

Comment: (+1) because this answer explains WHY we do not necessarily run into a contradiction rather than just mentioning the truth table.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing is to realise that $q \to r$ is true already if $q$ is *false*. So also $p \to \lnot p$ is true if $p$ is false. This is contrary to the usage people expect in English or natural language.

Comment: Is this a convention that $q\impliesr$ is true or is there a series of steps that get from sentence to the conclusion?  I am very new to this, so please excuse me if my question does not make sense

Comment: @GeoGraphy this is how the truth of an implication is * defined* in logic. See its truth table.